# OpenGL update for intel graphic

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, opengl, amd-graphics

It all started with me wanting to use `OpenGL 4` to play games on my ubuntu 16.04 laptop. I was running on intel integrated graphics and even if the processor is suppose to handle `OpenGL 4` I could not find a way to install it as intel drivers are already installed on 16.04.

However i quickly realized that I have another video adapter on my laptop : `[AMD/ATI] Mars XTX [Radeon HD 8790M]`

So I tried to make this one work by installing AMD proprietary drivers (`fglrx`). I activated them in the additional driver setting but I cannot for some reason switch from intel graphic to my AMD GPU.

I looked everywhere and trying a bit everything. Using `amdconfig` gives me: `no suported adapter detected`.

I am running out of ideas and would appreciate any advise.
P.S: I am no expert at ubuntu.

EDIT: AMD proprietary driver do not work on ubuntu 16.04. I would therefore try to get OpenGL 4 to work on intel graphics. The only information I got as for driver is that it is i915. The laptop has a i7-4810MQ which runs Intel® HD Graphics 4600. This is suppose to run openGL 4.3 ....

Answer (score 1):

`fglrx` is not supported on 16.04.  See [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04) for more details.

Comment: Great, so I am better off with the intel HD graphics since AMD open source driver won't support openGL...